# .htaccess redirect all subfolders to http except main domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdirectory

**Hello!**
Please help me!
I have a main domain "domain.com"
And i have a subfolders 
**--folder_one

--folder_two

--folder_three

--folder_four

...**

How can i, using, htaccess, redirect users from http://example.com to https://example.com and if user going to any subfolder in this domain redirect him to http of this, 
**Example: https://example.com/folder_one to https://example.com/folder_one**

I have done this, but i get a permanent redirect.
Please help.

Many thanks!

Comment: Source and target are the same

Answer (score 0):

This redirect main domain to http and subfolders to https. I want exactly the opposite

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on 
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```